# How to request manifest version number of chrome extension to display in popup.html?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, get, version, manifest

<s>Here is what I have, but it's not working:</s>

```
chrome.manifest = (function() {
    var manifestObject = false;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            manifestObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL('../manifest.json'), false);

    try {
        xhr.send();
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('Couldn\'t load manifest.json');
    }

    return manifestObject;

})();
function versionNumber() {
chrome.app.getDetails().version
}
function myVersion2() {
return versionNumber();
}
```

The value that is returned is `undefined`
The value that **should** be returned is the version number of the extension; i.e. **1.0**

If you have a better or simpler or easier method, feel free to post it. All I need to to return the version number in `function myVersion2()`

---

**SOLVED!**

Solved, all I had to do was this:

```
function myVersion2() {
return chrome.app.getDetails().version;
}
```

I could delete everything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the manifest version is held in `chrome.app.getDetails().manifest_version`. Is this what you were after?

Comment: Yes, but if I hadn't already figured it out, I wouldn't know what you meant though. Post the code that I already posted in my answer and I'll go ahead and accept as best answer.